# Error en Flutter con Firebase Dart -> Error: Unhandled exception

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-auth

Estoy conectando mi app en Flutter con Firebase, pero estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de leer los datos de Firebase. Esto es lo que tengo escrito:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  final FirebaseUser user;
  const Home({
    Key key,
    this.user
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Home ${user.email}"),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
        stream: Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(user.uid).snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot){
          if(snapshot.hasError){
            return Text("Error: $snapshot.error");
          }
          switch(snapshot.connectionState){
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return Text("Loading");
            default:
              return checkRole(snapshot.data);
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Center checkRole(DocumentSnapshot snapshot){
    if(snapshot.data['role'] == 'admin'){
      return adminPage(snapshot);
    } else{
      return userPage(snapshot);
    }
  }

  Center adminPage(DocumentSnapshot snapshot){
    return Center(child: Text(snapshot.data['role'] + ' PAGE'));
  }

  Center userPage(DocumentSnapshot snapshot){
    return Center(child: Text(snapshot.data['role']));
  }
}
```

El problema es q se queda cargando (en la parte del switch) y no avanza. Probe a eliminar el switch y poner un else {return checkRole(snapshot.data)}, para eliminar la parte de loading, pero sigue sin funcionar.

Este es el error:

```
E/flutter ( 4074): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(209)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter ( 4074): MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method DocumentReference#addSnapshotListener on channel plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore)
E/flutter ( 4074): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:159:7)
E/flutter ( 4074): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 4074): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:334:12)
E/flutter ( 4074): #2      MethodChannelDocumentReference.snapshots.<anonymous closure> (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_document_reference.dart:93:50)
E/flutter ( 4074): #3      _runGuarded (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:823:24)
E/flutter ( 4074): #4      _BroadcastStreamController._subscribe (dart:async/broadcast_stream_controller.dart:213:7)
E/flutter ( 4074): #5      _ControllerStream._createSubscription (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:836:19)
E/flutter ( 4074): #6      _StreamImpl.listen (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:493:9)
E/flutter ( 4074): #7      new _ForwardingStreamSubscription (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:118:10)
E/flutter ( 4074): #8      _ForwardingStream._createSubscription (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:88:16)
E/flutter ( 4074): #9      _ForwardingStream.listen (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:83:12)
E/flutter ( 4074): #10     _StreamBuilderBaseState._subscribe (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:139:37)
E/flutter ( 4074): #11     _StreamBuilderBaseState.didUpdateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:124:7)
E/flutter ( 4074): #12     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4734:58)
E/flutter ( 4074): #13     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3245:15)
E/flutter ( 4074): #14     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4571:16)
E/flutter ( 4074): #15     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4262:5)
E/flutter ( 4074): #16     StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4627:5)
E/flutter ( 4074): #17     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3245:15)
E/flutter ( 4074): #18     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4571:16)
E/flutter ( 4074): #19     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4262:5)
E/flutter ( 4074): #20     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4906:5)
E/flutter ( 4074): #21     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3245:15)
E/flutter ( 4074): #22     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4571:16)
E/flutter ( 4074): #23     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4262:5)
E/flutter ( 4074): #24     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4906:5)
E/flutter ( 4074): #25     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3245:15)
E/flutter ( 4074): #26     RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5566:32)
E/flutter ( 4074): #27     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6001:17)
E/flutter ( 4074): #28     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3245:15)
E/flutter ( 4074): #29     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4571:16)
E/flutter ( 4074): #30     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4719:11)
E/flutter ( 4074): #31     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4262:5)
E/flutter ( 4074): #32     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4751:5)
E/flutter ( 4074): #33     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3245:15)
E/flutter ( 4074): #34     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4571:16)
E/flutter ( 4074): #35     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4262:5)
E/flutter ( 4074): #36     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4906:5)
E/flutter ( 4074): #37     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3245:15)
E/flutter ( 4074): #38     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4571:16)
E/flutter ( 4074): #39     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4719:11)
E/flutter ( 4074): #40     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4262:5)
E/flutter ( 4074): #41     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4751:5)
E/flutter ( 4074): #42     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3245:15)
E/flutter ( 4074): #43     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5881:14)
E/flutter ( 4074): #44
```

Por si no quedo claro, simplemente quiero mostrar el texto de la base de datos en la pagina. Ejecute flutter clean, flutter doctor, flutter upgrade y flutter pub get, y sigue sin funcionar. Tambien elimine el emulador y lo volvi a instalar, al igual que con la app.

Este seria el pubspect.yaml:

```
name: flutterfirebase
description: A new Flutter application.
publish_to: 'none'
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_auth: ^0.16.1
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.6
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

Archivo android/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Y finalmente android/app/build.gradle:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.flutterfirebase"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

La version de flutter es la ultima (Flutter 1.20.0-1.0.pre.42) aunque prove con la version anterior y tampoco funcionaba. Dart esta en la version 2.9.0. Y finalmente uso Android Studio.

Comment: que version de flutter tienes ? puedes agregar tu pubspec.yaml ? sobre que simulador estás corriendo?

Comment: Añadidos todos los cambios

Answer (score 0):

has leido bien a la hora de integrar tu firebase con tu proyecto??
me refiero a como instalar en tu proyecto 'com.google.gms.google-services'. derrepente la falla la encuentras ay, por lo que veo en tu "apply plugin: no veo ningun plugin de 'com.google.gms.google-services' revisa eso y testea todo de nuevo ver que sale,
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Answer (score 0):

El 'apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' que tienes al final del build.gradle(app) debes ubicarlo justo después de 'apply plugin: 'com.android.application'.

Ademas el minSdkVersion debe estar 21 si deseas usar CloudFirestore, y eso debería ser lo que esta fallando.

Answer (score 0):

- Tienes este tipo de error Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException
- MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method DocumentReference#addSnapshotListener on channel plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore)

Nota: Si no tienes mucho tiempo prueba editando el AppDelegate.h del paso 5

**¡¡ESTO CASO ES DESPUÉS de actualizar proyectos de Android anteriores a 1.12 !!**

Paso después de actualizar siguiendo la guía: [Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects) aplica las siguientes acciones:

1. Actualiza flutter a su última versión estable -> flutter clean
2. Actualice todas sus dependencias (es muy probable que los paquetes tengan o le pidan que agregue nuevos métodos) -> flutter clean
3. Actualice el código y los métodos resultantes de la actualización del paquete.
4. Pruebe flutter run o desde Android Studio |> (algunos paquetes pueden enviarle missingPluginException, pero si está instalado en el móvil) vaya al paso 5.
5. Cree las instalaciones de prueba para Android e IOS si puede (deberían funcionar bien).
   Es probable que en desarrollo con flutter run continúe enviando el error, en mi caso no puedo probar en IOS pero con flutter run se ejecuta tanto para android como para IOS  y el problema se resuelve agregándolo a ios / Runner / AppDelegate.h  [GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:self];

```
#import <Flutter / Flutter.h>
#import <UIKit / UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate
  [GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:self];
@Fin
```

Si después de estos pasos no se puede ejecutar en el paso 4 0 5, verifique que otras dependencias no hayan actualizado sus versiones para que sean compatibles con Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects!. Por ejemplo, si un paquete usa o depende de otro paquete, si puede desinstale uno.
Repita desde el paso 4 nuevamente.